# How can you do multiple membership tests in SQL without subqueries?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm sure this is a very easy SQL question but I'm afraid my SQL-fu is still not up to snuff for me to be able to figure it out.

I have a table of sales orders and a table of customers. Each sales order has an ID for the customer to whom it will be billed, and an ID for the customer to whom it will be shipped (they may be the same, but most often not - there is a one-to-many relationship between a "bill to" and "ship to" [e.g. let's say I'm selling something to Google, the "bill to" would be Google's Mountain View headquarters, but the "ship to" might be Google's Geneva office.)

So I've got a query that basically asks the following question:
"Give me the total sales from the sales order table where this customer's Bill To is associated with John Doe or this customer's Ship To is associated with John Doe, but not the Bill To as well."

and the query I have is fairly straightforward (read: naive)

```
    SELECT SUM(price) FROM salesOrders
    WHERE
    (
    ( salesOrders.BillTo IN (SELECT customerID FROM customers WHERE customers.salesman = 'JOHNDOE')

    OR

    (salesOrders.ShipTo IN (SELECT customerID FROM customers WHERE customers.salesman = 'JOHNDOE') 
AND 
salesOrders.BillTo NOT IN (SELECT customerID FROM customers WHERE customers.salesman = 'JOHNDOE')
    )
    )
```

The query works, but it just takes way too long (~6 sec to execute). I'm almost positive there is a very easy way to either extract the subquery so I don't have it triplicated or remove the subqueries altogether and replace them with joins, I just don't know how to do it. :( On the plus side, this might be easy points for someone out there :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(so.price) 
    FROM salesOrders so
        LEFT JOIN customers c1
            on so.BillTo = c1.customerID
                and c1.salesman = 'JOHNDOE'
        LEFT JOIN customers c2
            on so.ShipTo = c2.customerID
                and c2.salesman = 'JOHNDOE'
    WHERE c1.customerID IS NOT NULL
        OR (c2.customerID IS NOT NULL AND c1.customerID IS NULL)
```

Comment: will the `NULL` comparisons be faster than @Dan's comparison between the fields?

Comment: @Matthew PK: It's hard to tell without seeing the real data, but I'm concerned that [Dan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818855/how-can-you-do-multiple-membership-tests-in-sql-without-subqueries/4819007#4819007) could return incorrect results. It seems to me that 'JOHNDOE' could be the `salesman` on both `BillTo` and `ShipTo` accounts, even if their IDs (`BillTo`, `ShipTo`) are different.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(s.price)
FROM salesOrders s
  inner join customers bt on s.billto = bt.customerID
  inner join customers st on s.ShipTo = st.customerID
WHERE
  s.billto <> s.shipto and 'JONHDOE' in (bt.salesman, st.salesman);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what database engine you are using, but if it is powerful will allow you tocreate temporary/variable tables.

I'm sure you have noticed, you are useing the same select 3 times, it might be more useful if performed once, save results to a temporary table and delete it after use.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that would do most performance boost is having the correct indexing. 
You dont say which SQL server your running if it's SQL 2008 it will give you hints of index to add when looking at the query plan.

I Prefer using exists, there is not much performance gain using it as far as i have been able to tell. You should look at the queryplan to check.

```
 SELECT SUM(price) FROM salesOrders
            WHERE
            EXISTS (SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 
                                customers.salesman = 'JOHNDOE'
                                and ( (salesOrders.ShipTo = customers.CustomerId  
                                        and not salesOrders.BillTo = customers.CustomerId)                  
                                or salesOrders.BillTo = customers.CustomerId
                             ) )
```

Comment: This result will exclude any "ShipTo" customers where the salesman has **ever** billed to.

Comment: @Matthew indeed very sloppy of me! I changed the query.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you have an id column(s) in `salesOrders` (here referred to just as `ID`):

```
SELECT SUM(s.Price)
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Price, ShipTo AS CustomerID FROM salesOrders
  UNION
  SELECT ID, Price, BillTo FROM salesOrders
) s
  INNER JOIN customers c ON s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE c.salesman = 'JOHNDOE'
```

UNION eliminates the duplicates, so cases where `BillTo` is identical to `ShipTo` will not be calculated twice.